# Maximum call stack size exceeded at stringify in Stripe api

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, stripe-payments

I am using stripe api in my backend node js.

```
const checkOutSession = asyncHandler(async(req,res)=>{
    
    const checkOut = await CheckOut.findById(req.params.id)
    console.log(checkOut.lineItems)
 
    
   const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
       payment_method_types: ['card'],
       line_items : checkOut.lineItems ,
       mode: 'payment',
       success_url: `${process.env.BASE_URL}/payment?success=true`,
       cancel_url: `${process.env.BASE_URL}/payment?canceled=true`,
   })
  
   res.json({sessionId : session.id})
})
```

My model is like this

```
const checkOutSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    user:{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref:'user',
        required:true
    },
    lineItems:[{
        _id:false,
        price_data:{
            currency: {
                type:String,
                default: 'usd'
            },
            product_data:{
                name:{
                    type:String,
                    required:true
                },
                images:[String]
            },
            unit_amount:{
                type:Number,
                required:true
            },
           
        },
        quantity:{
            type:Number,
            required:true
        }
    }],
    isPaid:{
        type:Boolean,
        default:false
    }
})
```

I figured that problem lies in line_items: checkOut.lineItems. When I hardcode line_items , it works fine but when I use checkOut.lineItems in line_items , I get error like this:

RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
[0]     at Function.[Symbol.hasInstance] ()
[0]     at stringify (F:\Coding Projects\Mern\Mobile\node_modules\qs\lib\stringify.js:65:20)
[0]     at stringify (F:\Coding Projects\Mern\Mobile\node_modules\qs\lib\stringify.js:125:33)

when I console.log checkOut.lineItems , it logs properly as format shown in stripe documentation.
console.log shows as

```
[
[0]   {
[0]     price_data: { product_data: [Object], currency: 'usd', unit_amount: 499 },
[0]     quantity: 1
[0]   },
[0]   {
[0]     price_data: { product_data: [Object], currency: 'usd', unit_amount: 499 },
[0]     quantity: 1
[0]   }
[0] ]
```

It only works when I hardcode that value but not dynamically. If I console.log JSON.Stringify(checkOut.lineItems) it comes like

```
[
[0]   {
[0]     "price_data": {
[0]       "product_data": {
[0]         "images": [
[0]           "https://res.cloudinary.com/saralkarki/image/upload/v1620276206/MobiHub/MI/Mi%2011%20Lite/xiaomi-mi-11-lite-4g-blue-600x600_v8r10l.jpg"
[0]         ],
[0]         "name": "Xiaomi Mi 11 Lite"
[0]       },
[0]       "currency": "usd",
[0]       "unit_amount": 499
[0]     },
[0]     "quantity": 1
[0]   },
[0]   {
[0]     "price_data": {
[0]       "product_data": {
[0]         "images": [
[0]           "https://res.cloudinary.com/saralkarki/image/upload/v1620275521/MobiHub/MI/Redmi%20Note%2010/xiaomi-redmi-note-10-thumb-green-600x600_ntavlj.jpg"
[0]         ],
[0]         "name": "Xiaomi Redmi Note 10"
[0]       },
[0]       "currency": "usd",
[0]       "unit_amount": 499
[0]     },
[0]     "quantity": 1
[0]   }
[0] ]
```

Comment: It looks like you have a circular reference somewhere, but that can't be deduced from the presented information. What is `product_data`?

Comment: {
[0]   images: [
[0]     'https://res.cloudinary.com/saralkarki/image/upload/v1620276206/MobiHub/MI/Mi%2011%20Lite/xiaomi-mi-11-lite-4g-blue-600x600_v8r10l.jpg'
[0]   ],
[0]   name: 'Xiaomi Mi 11 Lite'

Comment: if i log product_data it comes like this. ignore that [0]. It is just from console

Comment: Please can you be a little more accurate in the information that you are providing? Please add the output of the following statement `console.log(JSON.stringify(checkOut.lineItems, null, 2))` to **the body** of your question. If this also blows up, please add that information too.

Comment: @spender . I put your statement in the question. I dont think stringify will work because if I hardcode the value from my console.log(checkOut.lineItems) it works . Just it doesnot work if i put it directly

Answer (score 0):

I highly believe it is because you have a circular reference in your product_data. The circular dependency is a problem that happens due to `strigify` being a recursive function. And trust me... this is catchy... you might think "hey! my console.log works fine". Well... here is the thing, console.log goes just prints the object until a certain level, and is able to detect circular reference and ignore them...

So, for example, consider this...

```js
const a = {};
const b = {a};
a.b = b;

console.log('fine', b); // works fine

console.log('not fine', JSON.stringify(a)); // blows up the code
```

So to solve your issue you need to look into your product_data and remove any circular reference it might have. If you create a parser that only returns the required fields you could solve your problema easily.

Comment: So ,can you help me fix the code? My mind is complete blank

Answer (score 0):

This seems unrelated to the stripe-node package, and only an issue with stringifying the object. Possibly your `checkOut.lineItems` is some non-standard structure from the mongo scheme. You say it logs correctly with `JSON.stringify` but the error shows that `qs.stringify` is being used, possible related to the mongo `toString()` definition.

To test this, you could *try*:

```
line_items: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(checkOut.lineItems)),
```

if that works, you're at least right that all the needed data is there and you have a problem with stringification to resolve. I wouldn't recommend the above outside of a debugging context.

Comment: Your answer worked. Can you explain me any reason to stringify then parse again?

Comment: You absolutely should not do this for real, it should not be necessary -- this was merely a diagnostic. It shows there is something about your object structure that make `qs.stringify` fail even though `JSON.stringify` works. I really don't know what that is but I'd suggest trimming the object down key by key to see what makes it fail then correct that.

Comment: You might be able to leverage the `toJSON()` method mongoose has on documents that gets used by JSON.stringify: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-toJSON
Try: `line_items : checkOut.lineItems.toJSON(),`

Comment: toJSON() didnot work. I fixed it by making new array and pushed the lineItems in that array. Is this solution good or what do you suggest? @Nolan

Comment: In what way did it "not work"? I would be surprised if it was the same error. Building a new array and pushing the entries is likely solving the underlying issue with your original data structure, even if we don't know what the exact issue is. If this works for you, great! There are likely other solutions, but what you describe isn't a bad option.

Comment: toJSON() returns error as toJSON is not function.

Comment: Oh, really? Huh, the docs suggested to me that was on everything. Does `checkOut.toJSON` exist?